# how to handle query execution time (performance issue ) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have situation need to execute patch script for million row of data.The current query execution time is not meet the expectation for few rows (18000) which is take around 4 hours( testing data before deploy for live ).
The patch script actually select million row of data in loop and update according to the specification , im just wonder how long it could take for million row of data since it take around 4 hour for just 18000 rows.

to overcome this problem im decided to create temp table hold the entire select statement data and proceed with the patch process using the temp table where the process could be bit faster compare select and update.

is there any other ways i can use to handle this situation ? Any suggestion and ways to solve this.

(Due to company policy im unable to post the PL/SQl script here )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there is no one can answer my question here i post my answer.
In oracle there is Parallel Execution which is allows spreading the processing of a single SQL statement across multiple threads.

So by using this method i solved my long running query (4 hours ) to 6 minz ..

For more information :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database-performance/geist-parallel-execution-1-1872400.html

Comment: It is a bit difficult to give hints for speeding up a query without the query. Besides executing it in parallel you also should have a look at the execution plan of your query (see explain in the oracle documentation).

Comment: @UweAllner yes , i was studied about that too and changed the execution plan so the now its more faster then my original query , thanks for your comment.